# Maximum memory on 32-bit Windows 7…

Tags: windows-7, memory, ramdisk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [can a 32-bit OS machine use up all 8GB RAM + 20GB page file?](https://superuser.com/questions/367490/can-a-32-bit-os-machine-use-up-all-8gb-ram-20gb-page-file)

I understand that I will not be able to use a full 4 GB on my 32-bit Windows 7 installation. I ready have two gigs installed on my machine and a friend just gave me another two gig stick. So what can I do with the memory that is above the Win7 "limit"? A RAM disk? Faster/better video? Nothing?

Ross

Comment: Take a look at this http://superuser.com/questions/367490/can-a-32-bit-os-machine-use-up-all-8gb-ram-20gb-page-file

Comment: Windows will be unable address anything beyond 3.2GB of memory.  The rest of the address space will be used by hardware.  I won't bother with providing a more detailed answer, this has been asked a million times, and there are a million and one accurate answers.

Comment: @Ramhound I guess you missed this W7 hack...http://www.unawave.de/windows-7-tipps/32-bit-ram-barrier.html?lang=EN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory above the limit is unavailable, so you can do *nothing* with it.

Unless you would enable PAE, such that you can access it just like the other memory is accessed, such that the limit is gone. But that slows down memory access a lot...

Answer (score 0):

You can't use it for anything, as far as i'm aware, unless the operating system can see it (which it can't). I believe the actual limit is 3.2gb, so you'll only be losing out on 800mb.