# Why can't x86 (32-bit) operating systems use more than 3.25 GB of RAM memory and not whole 4 GB?

Tags: windows-7, memory, 64-bit, operating-systems, 32-bit

I know that 32 bit machines cannot use more than 4 GB of RAM since they cannot address this many memory addresses.

However I do not understand why almost all 32 bit operating systems including Window 7 cannot use more than 3.25 GB

2^32 = 4294967296  bits which is 4 GB of RAM. On my machine however it says that only 3.25 GB are usable. Why can't the rest of MEMORY be used ?

I am not asking how it can be done. i want to know why exactly 3.25 GB . How is this value calculated. Where does it come from ?

Comment: "Why can't the rest of MEMORY be used ?" Microsoft designed Windows that way

Comment: @Ramhound that question does not answer my question. Why 3.25 GB? Why not 4 GB? Is this the answer ? Because microsoft wants it this way ? Since that question is not a duplicate of mine can you please remove the downvote you gave me ?

Comment: **I can't reverse a vote I didn't cast.**. I still feel it's a duplicate.   You do realize that voting is anonymous for a reason right, it's to stop people from calling each other out, for casting votes they don't agree with

Comment: The first duplicate has numerous answer that explains that 32-bit versions of Windows can address up to 4GB of memory.

Comment: Another possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/367490/can-a-32-bit-os-machine-use-up-all-8gb-ram-20gb-page-file another one: http://superuser.com/questions/27086/why-does-windows-only-show-about-3-5-gb-of-my-4-gb-of-ram/27089#27089 another one: http://superuser.com/questions/367490/can-a-32-bit-os-machine-use-up-all-8gb-ram-20gb-page-file/367525#367525

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 32 bit client version of Windows has a physical address space of 4 GB. It would be nice if all of this space could be used for RAM but that is not the case. A portion of this address space is used for memory mapped hardware devices. The CPU can communicate with these devices by reading or writing to their address space just as it does with RAM. There are other methods available but memory mapped hardware is much faster, important for high performance devices like video systems. Typically memory mapped devices consume about .5 to 1 GB but is tan be more or less in some cases.

You can't have 4 GB RAM and .5 to 1 GB memory mapped devices in the same 4 GB address space. It just won't fit. Thus whatever space is used for hardware devices is not available for RAM. If you have 3 GB or less RAM there is usually address space to spare and no RAM is lost.

If the address space used for hardware devices is subtracted from 4 GB that leaves about 3 to 3.5 space available for RAM. 3.25 GB is just typical and the number often quoted.

I suppose all of this could have been done differently but that would have complicated the design, and a 4 GB address space was huge at the time. Changing it now would have serious compatibility issues. And we already have a much better solution in using a 64 bit OS. A 64 bit OS has a much larger address space so there is plenty of room for everything.

PAE is often suggested as a solution. This is a special setting that allows for a much larger physical address space. Conflicting RAM can be addressed above 4 GB where it can then be addressed. This option is supported by 32 bit server operating systems. The problem was that many device drivers behaved very poorly in such an environment with very unfortunate results, such as crashes or data corruption. For that reason client systems simply ignore RAM above 4 GB. This has become a license restriction and enforced in the kernel.

As PAE doesn't work in client systems and 32 bit servers are virtually obsolete it is essentially a dead issue.

Comment: And just to be clear: "licensing restriction" = "Microsoft designed Windows that way" Probably for stability, sanity, and backwards compatibility.

Comment: @LMiller7 Thank you very much for this explanation. I now understand why this issue appears. Thanks.

Comment: PAE worked on Windows 7...

Comment: PAE works on Windows 7 32-bit editions but it doesn't let you access more than about the same limit. XP SP1 was the last version where that worked.