# How to Upgrade Memory From 2Gb To 8Gb?

Tags: memory, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I enable PAE on Windows 7 (32-bit) to support more than 3.5 GB of RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/52275/how-can-i-enable-pae-on-windows-7-32-bit-to-support-more-than-3-5-gb-of-ram)

I have a laptop which has 2GB DDR III RAM, 520MX 1GB Graphic, and Intel Core i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz.

I use W7 32bit (I don't want to use 64bit W7), and I don't have enough RAM for some applications something like I am using Virtual Machines, MS Office 2010, PS5, CorelDraw X5, Nero 11, MS Visual Studio 2010, and many others. So I added two 4GB RAM for the machine. But I found that only 2.66GB usable instead of 8.00GB. Is there anything else I need to change in my system?

Comment: You shouldnt mix RAM like that. Also requires 64-bit windows

Comment: *> You shouldnt mix RAM like that. Also requires 64-bit windows*   What mixing? Both replacement sticks are 4GB, presumably from a kit.

Comment: Sorry, but the answer is basically "too bad". The x86 architecture is inherently restricted on a physical level to ~3GB of RAM. You can kind of use PAE as a workaround, see link above. But why don't you want to use Windows x64? Perhaps there's a deeper problem we can help you solve?

Comment: Disable memory remapping in the BIOS (if it allows it). This might get you an extra 800MB or so.

Comment: Both replacement sticks are 4GB. Anyway, Thank you all, I finally installed W7 x64.

Answer (score 0):

Your system has 1 GiB of graphics memory, and only 32 bits with which to address memory.

That means you have 2<sup>32</sup> - 2<sup>30</sup> = 3 GiB of address space left.

Subtracting away other device ranges and the amount of RAM that the OS needs, that leaves you with the ~2.6 GiB you mentioned.

Of course, applications probably won't be able to even use *that* much, because 1 GiB of address space is reserved for the kernel.

Comment: Then, tell me how to do? Upgrade W7 64bits?

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension)'s a list of Microsoft operating systems and their maximum memory sizes.

Comment: @WadiNaw: Yeah.