# Max amount of RAM for windows 7 on core duo

Tags: windows-7

I have a core duo system with DDR3 RAM 2 GB. My motherboard says it can handle 8 GB of RAM. My question is if I add 8 gb RAM to system will windows7 32 bit  support it?

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't - 32bit OS can only use 4Gb RAM. And some of this will be reserved for the OS, giving you about 3GB RAM for your programs.

You need a 64bit OS to use more than 4GB RAM (assuming the software is also 64bit).

Furthermore, as per Michael Kjörling excellent comments, *"Even if you use only 32-bit applications on a 64-bit OS, each application can get its own 4 GiB virtual address space. So even such an environment can benefit from >4 GiB RAM."*

Comment: Even if you use only 32-bit applications on a 64-bit OS, each application can get its own 4 GiB virtual address space. So even such an environment can benefit from >4 GiB RAM.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - I agree, but, let's not confuse the OP :) Although thank you for the comment, I will include in my answer.

Comment: Not wanting to confuse the OP is why I didn't mention the fact that a segmented memory model could, in principle, work just as well in a 32-bit environment as in a 16-bit environment, so saying that a 32-bit OS "can only use 4 GB of RAM" is a bit of a misnomer. ;-) For most commonly available 32-bit OSes, definitely.

Comment: A 32-bit application will only use more than 2 GB of user mode virtual address space if it is marked large address space aware. However the OP was asking about physical memory.

Comment: That is a terrible nonsense which most people are believing. Even back in the last decade I was using a Xeon (with 32 bit) an 8 GB RAM (HP ProLiant). So also 32 Bit Windows can use over 4 GB RAM.

Comment: @Offler -http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Offler - Except were not talking about Windows Server software we are talking about Windows 7 x86 and it only supports 4GB.

Comment: yep. But you will also find manuals on the internet how to use PAE and Windows 7 32 bit and more then 4 GB RAM. Microsoft (and most linux ditributions) don't like 32 bit and more RAM. But it is possible. oh, and as you like links one to ano older superuser.com entry: http://superuser.com/questions/52275/how-can-i-enable-pae-on-windows-7-32-bit-to-support-more-than-3-5-gb-of-ram

Comment: @Offler - this is just bonkers. There is a reason it was removed and requires patching/updating etc to use it!

Comment: Still for many 32 bit OS (like 2008 Datacenter Edition) it is still in , therefore the general: "32bit OS can only use 4Gb RAM" is wrong. So the reason seems not to be seen as so critical in more critical environments...

Comment: @Offler - The user is not using a 10k+ operating system like Windows Server 2008 Datacenter Edition.  Furthermore the comments I have made and others have made have been directed to 32-bit Windows 7 not Windows Server which ( by the way ) is no longer offered as a 32-bit operating system.

Comment: I think the point is that even if "32-bit OSes can only use 4GB" is wrong (because of PAE), but this misses the point that "Windows 7 32-bit can only use 4GB" is right. So regardless of whether Dave is wrong on a technicality, his answer of "no, Win7 x86 can only use 4GB of RAM" is substantively correct.

Answer (score 0):

No it won't, you'd need to go to 64bit. officially 32bit only supports 4Gb but you'll only ever see about 3.2Gb.

Comment: Is this not what I wrote?

Comment: @Offler - Except they are right.  Windows 7 x86 only supports 4GB.

Comment: @RamHound they are completly wrong. look in the other comment.

Comment: @Offler - So your counter argument is PAE, you have to be kidding me, that causes all sorts of problems on your everyday desktop computer.  As for hacking the kernel....You have to be kidding me.

Comment: No, my counter argument against the general " 32 bit os can only use 4GB" is: 1. there are still alot systems which can use more memory out of the box (like 2008 DataCenter, some Linuxes etc.pp". 2. Also on the other ones there are chances to enable it. It is no general rule of thumb that a 32 bit os can only use 4gb. and by the way: why do you think the server editions are still able to use PAE - and are normally used for more critical operations? From a long time back MS just does not want that consumer systems are used as servers (price). That as one of the main reasons.

Comment: @Offler - Again...This answer was in reference to Windows 7 not Windows Server 2008 or Linux.  The only way for a 32-bit Windows 7/Windows Vista/Windows 8 system to use more then 4GB ( even with PAE enabled ) is to hack the kernel.