# max Ram size in 32-bit system

Tags: 32-bit, computer-architecture

I know that on 32 bit system max number of memory cells in RAM is 2^32. But RAM in my computer show not exactly this size. Can someone explain why on 32 bit system size of RAM not equal max size of cells but varies(3.2 - 3.6 Gb)?

Comment: Where are you getting that max-ram information? Is this a Windows machine and you are viewing the Computer properties page?

Comment: @user2135931 - What operating system are we talking about?  Required reading before you reply to my question: http://superuser.com/questions/52275/how-can-i-enable-pae-on-windows-7-32-bit-to-support-more-than-3-5-gb-of-ram?rq=1

Comment: see http://superuser.com/questions/27086/why-does-windows-only-show-about-3-5-gb-of-my-more-than-4-gb-of-ram for your answer

Comment: 32-bit systems can have more than 2^32 "memory cells". Memory is addressed in bytes, not "memory cells", so that gets you to 4 GB. Physical address extension allows more than 4 GB, though often only the OS will have all memory available to it, and individual applications will have a maximum of 4 GB assigned to them.

Answer (score 0):

Two obvious possibilities come to mind:

1. Your 32-bit system supports 4 GB, but you haven't actually installed that much memory.
2. Windows reports less than 4 GB available, because some of the main memory has been reserved for use by the integrated graphics.